# innerHtml to string get indexOf (wildcard) is this possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, wildcard, indexof

I have an HTML element `<tmp></tmp>` inside a parent container.

In my function I use a global variable called divText which is the `parentContainer.html().toString()`;

I want to avoid going back to the DOM, and use the passed global variable `divText` to determine if the HTML element "tmp" contains only one character (any one character);

If I want to see if the `tmp` element is empty I use:

```
if(divText.indexOf('<tmp></tmp>') > -1){
/*I know the tmp container is Empty and exists*/
}
```

Is there such a function to determine if the tmp element contains one character, like so:

```
if(divText.indexOf('<tmp>(wildcard for any one char)</tmp>') > -1){
/*So i can know if the tmp container contains one character of any kind including space*/
}
```

Does such a function exists?

Comment: Get rid of `.html()` (and the useless `.toString()`) and work with `container` directly.

Comment: I re-worded the question, i see your confusion, my apologies. Please check again.

Comment: _“Does such a function exists?”_ - no, it doesn’t. You would have to write it yourself, or use a regular expression instead - if you insist on doing this on a text level. If you keep this in the DOM - then all you have to do is find that `tmp` element, and check how long its  `textContent` or `innerText` is.

Comment: could you give me an example of a regular expression for this? Presently i am using the method you suggested but it takes me back to the DOM. It is working though just seems untidy to me.. ALso this function repeats every 0020 while keydown is pressed..

Comment: @CBroe You gave me an idea: what about this, I'm asking opinion for speed:  if i make this:, var test = divText then replace the <tmp>and contents</tmp> with say these characters <*> and then get the length of test string minus 3(three) for the characters and compare it to the length of the divText string then if the difference is equal to 12(twelve) then i know the temp container contains one character? 12(twelve) is the number of characters in <tmp>(5) + </tmp>(6) + 1(for inside character) makes twelve..   How do you think this would fair on performance compared to going to the DOM again?

Comment: What “going to the DOM again” are we talking abouit here? How many hundred thousand times will you have to do this, that performance becomes a concern for something this minor to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe basically everytime a user hits a key on a keyboard this function fires, if they keep the key presses it fires repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

ok i figured it out: Even simpler then i thought.

```
/*duplicate the divText into variable test*/
var test = divText;
/*use regext to replace the temp container and contents with nothing*/
var test = test.replace(/<tmp>(.*)<\/tmp>/, '');
/*Here we check the length of the original divText with the test string to see if    it matches the characters for <tmp>(5) + </tmp>(6) + 1(for contents) ofcourse if you ever need something like this you can increase the one to what ever count you want*/
if((divText.length - test.length) == 12){
/*Here if there is one character inside do what ever*/
func.clearTimers('move');
func.showHide(0);
return;
}
```

im happy with this.